# Instance variable in _form.html.erb not working for new_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I receive this error: NoMethodError in Admin::SuperCategories#new, undefined method `super_categories_path'. My path are well defined and the whole logic works with the admin edit path. For some reason it doesn't work for the admin new action. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

**admin/super_categories/index.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "Create a new Super Category", 
        new_admin_super_category_path, class: "button success right" %>
```

**admin/super_categories_controller.rb**

```
def new
    @super_category = SuperCategory.new
end
```

**admin/super_categories/new.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

**admin/super_categories/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@super_category) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description, rows: 6 %> 
  </div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit class: "button success medium"  %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :super_categories
end

resources :super_categories, only: [:show]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're forgetting the *admin* portion of your path. You need to let `form_for` know about it, or it looks for `super_categories_path` instead of `admin_super_categories_path`:

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @super_category] do |f| %>
```